# Select a edge in mxgraph

Tags: graph

i am using mxgraph to show the process. I need to select a edge programtically. The mxgraph provids selectEdges(true,false,false) which will select all the edges in the graph. But i need to select a particular edge in the graph.

Suppose if there is vertex1, vertex2 and vertex3. Each of these vertex is connected using edges. I need to select the edge between vertex2 and vertex3. Whether mxgraph provides any api to dod so? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mxGraph` class hold a `mxGraphSelectionModel` instance, which is where you perform most of the selection operations. `clear()` and `addCell(Object)` will give you the result you require.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `GraphComponent`.
Use `graphComponent.getCellAt(x,y)` ( x y are you mouse/click coordinates)
when you get the returned object, make sure it is an edge by checking the `boolean isEdge()`.
So if you have the x, y programatically you can use the same process I described.
For example u can get the common edge of two vertices and it would be your edge.